# Inner class seems unnecessary in the example given in On Java 8 by Bruce Eckel

Tags: java, interface, callback, inner-classes

Bruce Eckel gives the following example in Chapter Inner Classed of the book On Java 8 to demonstrate the necessity of using an inner class instead of implementing an interface. But I found the code works fine without the inner class. The code seems to compile and give the same result if you just implement the Incrementable interface for Callee2. Does Bruce Eckel gives an inappropriate example or do I miss something?

```
package innerclasses;

interface Incrementable {
    void increment();
}

// Very simple to just implement the interface:
class Callee1 implements Incrementable {
    private int i = 0;
    
    @Override
    public void increment() {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

class MyIncrement {
    public void increment() {
        System.out.println("Other operation");
    }
    
    static void f(MyIncrement mi) {
        mi.increment();
    }
}

// If your class must implement increment() in
// some other way, you must use an inner class:
//Why not just implement Incremetable??? I don't get it
class Callee2 extends MyIncrement {
    private int i = 0;
    
    @Override
    public void increment() {
        super.increment();
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    
    private class Closure implements Incrementable {
        @Override
        public void increment() {
            // Specify outer-class method, otherwise
            // you'll get an infinite recursion:
            Callee2.this.increment();
        }
    }
    
    Incrementable getCallbackReference() {
        return new Closure();
    }
}

class Caller {
    private Incrementable callbackReference;
    
    Caller(Incrementable cbh) {
        callbackReference = cbh;
    }
    
    void go() {
        callbackReference.increment();
    }
}

public class Callbacks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callee1 c1 = new Callee1();
        Callee2 c2 = new Callee2();
        MyIncrement.f(c2);
        Caller caller1 = new Caller(c1);
        Caller caller2 = new Caller(c2.getCallbackReference());
        caller1.go();
        caller1.go();
        caller2.go();
        caller2.go();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Other operation
1
1
2
Other operation
2
Other operation
3
```

Why not just implement the Incrementable interface for class Callee2? I tried that and it seems to work out fine.

```
...
class Callee2 extends MyIncrement implements Incrementable{
    ...
    // everything remains the same just comment out the inner class 
    // closure
}
```

In the book Bruce Eckel says:

> This shows a further distinction between implementing an interface in an outer class versus doing so in an inner class. Callee1 is clearly the simpler solution in terms of the code. Callee2 inherits from MyIncrement, which already has a different increment() method that does something unrelated to the one expected by the Incrementable interface. ***When MyIncrement is inherited into Callee2, increment() can’t be overridden for use by Incrementable, so you’re forced to provide a separate implementation using an inner class.***

I didn't see why I'm ***forced to*** use inner class since implementing the interface provides the exact same output. Could you please explain how the code may behave differently without the inner class?

Comment: How do you think this code should be written, without an inner class?

Comment: Thanks for noticing！ Just implement the Incrementable interface for class Callee， and comment out everything about inner class Closure. The code compiles and the output is the same @Sweeper

Comment: Spelling: [Eckel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Eckel)

Comment: You use this pattern if you do not want to implement `Incrementable` in `Callee2`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can get that. But I don't understand why the author emphasizes that you're forced to use inner class instead of implementing the interface.

Comment: Because the purpose of the example is to show you how to evade implementing the interface in the outer class, if you do not want to, as @MarkRotteveel has already stated.

Comment: The text you quote explains why: the `increment()` method `Callee2` inherited from `MyIncrement` does something else than an `Incrementable.increment()` is supposed to do. The purpose of the example is to show what you can do in situations where direct inheritance is not possible (or not desired for other design reasons). In that way, it shows the benefit/use case for inner classes.